# Objective-C macro to return a string with the function and the line number while accepting a string with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: objective-c, macros, logging

I've found a bunch of macro variations on how to use NSLog as a basis and adding **PRETTY_FUNC** and **LINE** but all the variations of those macros simply output the result to the console.

I'd like to have a macro that can take a format with a variable number of arguments, add the name of the method and line number where it was called and then return an NSString but so far, the compiler always complains where I call it. My latest version is as follow:

```
#define FileLog(format, ...) {\
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n  %s [Line %d] \n       %@",
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
__LINE__,
[NSString stringWithFormat:(format), ##__VA_ARGS__]];\
}
```

Each time I call it from my code, the compiler generates one of those errors:

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
```

I don't want to write a log class or use a framework for that. There must be a way to do that with a macro? Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is entirely possible with a macro, I think you just need a little more background on them.

First, macros are not functions, so the braces are unnecessary (and, in fact, are the cause of your error). A macro is really a fairly dumb "copy/paste" that is automated by the preprocessor, using syntax that it understands.

In order to define a macro that spans multiple lines and creates an NSString "in place", you have to escape the newlines with backslashes, like so:

```
#define FileLog(format, ...) \
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %s [Line %d] \n %@", \
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, \
    __LINE__, \
    [NSString stringWithFormat:format, ##__VA_ARGS__]]
```

Macros do not "return" like a function does, because, as I mentioned, they are merely a way to "copy/paste" text.

You can use it like so:

```
int num = 42;
NSLog(@"%@", FileLog(@"some number: %d", num));
```

If you were to look at the preprocessor output (the file that the preprocessor creates before compilation), the above example would expand to something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %s [Line %d] \n %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some number: %d", num]]);
```

Comment: You're totally right, inspector! Never had much use for macros except consuming them but now I understand a little better what you mean.

Comment: I guess you guys should see my answer down bellow!
It's pretty simple!
And also you can disable any logs by simply changing only one line in a configuration/definition file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

Create an include file

```
#define LOG_NOLOG_LEVEL 0
#define LOG_ERROR_LEVEL 1
#define LOG_WARN_LEVEL 2
#define LOG_INFO_LEVEL 3
#define LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL 4


#if LOG_HELPER_LEVEL >= LOG_DEBUG_LEVEL
    #define LOGDEBUG(...) {[LogHelper log:[NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]];}
#else
    #define LOGDEBUG(...)
#endif

#if LOG_HELPER_LEVEL >= LOG_INFO_LEVEL
    #define LOGINFO(...) {[LogHelper log:[NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]];}
#else
    #define LOGINFO(...)
#endif

#if LOG_HELPER_LEVEL >= LOG_WARN_LEVEL
    #define LOGWARN(...) {[LogHelper log:[NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]];}
#else
    #define LOGWARN(...)
#endif

#if LOG_HELPER_LEVEL >= LOG_ERROR_LEVEL
    #define LOGERROR(...) {[LogHelper log:[NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]];}
#else
    #define LOGERROR(...)
#endif
```

Then create a simple class LogHelper with a single class method as follows....

```
+ (void) log:(NSString *)message
{
    fputs([message cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], stderr);
}
```

Then in your code, you can put calls like...

```
LOGDEBUG(@"%s - %d Redirect response received\n%@",__FILE__,
                                __LINE__,[redirectRequest dumpInfo]);
```

You can set the LOG_HELPER_LEVEL to the level of logging you want to produce.  If you set the level at say LOG_WARN_LEVEL, then no code will be included in your app for INFO or DEBUG levels, so it's easy to package your app up for release.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

From [Viraj Thenuwara](http://viraj.me/), who was my iOS Senior developer who trained me :-)

This macro is much more simpler in its definition and also its usage, than the things mentioned above.

```
#define debug                   1

#if debug
    #define AppLog(fmt, ...)        NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
    #define AppLog(...)
#endif
```

And it's usage is as follows:

```
 NSString *url = @"http://google.com";    
 AppLog(@"url %@ and id %d", url, 5);
```

This **AppLog** line will print out it's given content only if the **debug** constant is equal to 1. **At the Production time or in anytime you don't want to print the log lines you can disable it by turning that 1 into 0.**

And it's console out put will be seen as follows:

[image]

Hope this will be helpful to someone else!
Cheers!